# Creating properties for Lua

Tags: c++, properties, lua

I wasn't sure how to word the title, but here we go.

Let's say I made a Lua function to create a 2D box appear on the screen - for example:

```
box = createObject("Box")
```

How would I create properties for `box` that would subsequently change how `box` looks or reacts? For example I may want to do

```
box.PositionX = 0
box.PositionY = 60
```

How do I do that in C++?

Comment: You are a bit too impatient. I needed some time for an acceptably-quality answer.

Comment: What have you tried? Examples available in multitude of places, just look in Programming in Lua (first Ed free at Lua.org). Once you've tried a few things come back and post a more specific question.

Comment: check out [luabridge](http://vinniefalco.com/LuaBridge/Manual.html) and [luabind](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/luabind/docs.html) and maybe google [first](http://lua-users.org/wiki/BindingCodeToLua).

Answer (score 0):

Just answering the direct question itself, things are simple:
Just use the standard metatable-aware add/set-table-index API.

If we look at how box itself should look, things get interesting:

1. If `createObject "Box"` returns a Lua table and you don't need to react immediately on change, just don't do anything special.
2. If `createObject "Box"` returns a Lua table but you need to react immediately, let it act as a proxy object, aka force using the metatable function by never adding that element to the table itself. Remap to another index or another table saved at a dedicated index or in the metatable/metatable function closures.
3. If `createObject "Box"` returns a userdata, do the same as for 2, maybe saving non-lua-values in C for faster access/higher efficiency, using the environment table for all other values.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand how do check for Lua table or Userdata?

Comment: With the `type`-function. Anyway, if you yourself write or modify `createObject "Box"` or what it returns, you should already know. Otherwise, why use the [C++] on your question?

Comment: I think you misunderstand the question. I want to be able to add properties to createObject "Box" with C++, which will be accessed with Lua.

Comment: In that case, clarify your question, especially what magic defines "property" for you. Ping me when you have done so and I might amend my answer appropriately.

Comment: If you take a look at my examples you will notice that for me properties mean to change the state of something.

Comment: That was handled in my answer. What don't you understand about it?